# VBA Worksheet_beforesave validation of fields

Tags: vba, excel

so before this worksheet_beforesave, i've have implemented a Worksheet_beforeclose and it works beautifully to check the validation before the users close the file. But was told that it is a bad function as it disables people from closing if they never fill up the form.

soi tried to move all the codes into beforesave instead so to the macro will check the fields before letting them save (Which sounds better as compared to not letting them close)

but just swtiching all the codes from Worksheet_Beforeclose to Worksheet_beforesave didnt work out.. it just became like a normal worksheet without checking and the fields i which i had wrote to check before saving didnt work and it actually allowed users to save..

**Here is my code**

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeSave(ByVal SaveAsUI As Boolean, Cancel As Boolean)

If Range("D18").Value = "" Then
    MsgBox "User required to fill in at least one requirement"
    Cancel = True

    Range("D18").Select
End If

If Range("D30").Value = "" Then
    MsgBox "User required to fill in date"
    Cancel = True

    Range("D30").Select
End If

If Range("D32").Value = "" Then
    MsgBox "User required to fill in the field"
    Cancel = True

    Range("D32").Select
End If

If Range("D34").Value = "" Then
    MsgBox "User required to fill in the field"
    Cancel = True

    Range("D34").Select
End If

End Sub
```

**So to make it short and sweet**

i moved the exact codes from Worksheet_Beforeclose to worksheet_beforesave, but it didnt work out and it the fields that were empty was still able to pass and let the user save it

Thanks in advance and thanks for your time!

Comment: Are you sure it checks the right worksheet? Did you try putting a breakpoint?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try moving your code back to Workbook_BeforeClose. and check if your workbook is saved or not with

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeClose(Cancel As Boolean)
If Not ThisWorkbook.Saved Then Cancel = True
End Sub
```

the property .saved will change if there are changes with the workbook, if not it will stay true and the user will be able to close your workbook.

**edit#1**

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeSave(ByVal SaveAsUI As Boolean, Cancel As Boolean)
  Dim rRange As Range, eCell As Range
  If ThisWorkbook.ReadOnly Or ThisWorkbook.Saved Then Exit Sub

  Set rRange = Range("D18,D30,D32,D34")
  For Each eCell In rRange
    If eCell.Value = "" Then
      MsgBox "User required to fill in at least one requirement"
      Cancel = True
      eCell.Select
      Exit For
    End If
  Next
End Sub
```

the line

```
  If ThisWorkbook.ReadOnly Or ThisWorkbook.Saved Then Exit Sub
```

checks if the workbooks is read only and if it is saved. and do not proceed if true.

the line

```
Set rRange = Range("D18,D30,D32,D34")
```

we set your ranges into one range and loop through them with

```
For Each eCell In rRange
```

Comment: Hi Romcel! thanks for the reply, i tried putting back the Workbook_Beforeclose followed by your code, it still prevents users from pressing the exit application.. and when i tried to make the fields empty and press on save, it still allows them to save

Comment: The function i need for the file is to allow them to close if they didnt fill up, BUT not allow them to save it. Thanks

Comment: Ok. I will try looking into your code as soon I get to my workplace.

Comment: okay thank you so much! Do remember that the code above that i gave, originally was in Workbook_close. But i figured that i should allow users to close the application even though they did not fill up BUT to not allow them to save if they didnt fill up mandatory fields

Thanks once again!

Comment: updated this answer. kindly check if its working now.

Comment: omg it works perfectly! But sorry if i sound stupid.. if i wanted to save the macro itself, how do i do it? I need to leave the mandatory fields blank before i saved it but it will backfire at myself

Comment: you can set the `application.enableevents` to false. Save your workbook. and set it back to true. And you can mark this answer that solves your problem

Comment: @user7809596, please set the `Application.EnableEvents` in the VBE's Immediate Window.

Comment: sorry Romcel, i dont really know how to use the application.enableevents = false correctly.. 

What i need to do now is to save the macro code (With the validation) so when the user opens this exact form, the macros will start to run.. but now it kinda backfires because let's say if i were to apply the application.enableevents = false, i can save it BUT, if i were to send this to the user, they will be able to bypass it too since it is saved to false.. help me please

Comment: @user7809596 well, you told me that the codes are working. but you are not able to save it because the validation runs when you save it right? now do this steps **1)** open vba editor **2)** press CTRL+G **3)** type `application.enableevents = false` **4)** save your file **5)** put it back to true.

Comment: yes sir, codes is exactly working the way it is. (it's kinda hard to explain..) i need it to run the validation when the user opens the excel file that i will be sending them. but since i am able to save because of the application.enableevents = false inside the macro, it means that the file that the user will be getting from me will also contains the application.enableevents = false.. get what i meant? So sorry for the trouble..

Comment: @user7809596 no do not put it in the macro. just run the command in the **immediate window** in the **Visual Basic for Application** window

Comment: OHHH so it is somehow temporary and do not affect the macro? i see!! OMG THANKS ROMCEL YOU ARE THE MAN